# Си запись лишних символов в файл

Tags: c, файлы

Уже задавал вопрос по своей программе, но возникла новая проблема
Суть - в файле все отрицательные числа заменить нулём. Проблема возникает в том, что, судя по всему, цикл работает некорректно, и откуда-то в файл из буферного файла дописываются лишние числа.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void open_file(char *arg,FILE **addr1,FILE **addr2){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    *addr1=fopen(arg,"r+"); *addr2=fopen("buf.txt","w+");
    printf("1\n");
    if(*addr1==NULL){
        printf("Не могу открыть файл %s\n, проверьте аргумент", arg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void transform(FILE **addr1,FILE **addr2){
    int res,x,ch;
    printf("1\n"); 
    for(;;){
        res=fscanf(*addr1,"%d",&x);
        printf("1\n");
        if(res<=0) {
            fputc(x=EOF,*addr2);
            break;
            }
        if(x<0) x=0;
        fprintf(*addr2,"%d ",x);
    }
    printf("1\n");
    fseek(*addr1,0,SEEK_SET);
    fseek(*addr2,0,SEEK_SET);
    while ((ch=fgetc(*addr2))!=EOF){
        fputc(ch,*addr1);
    }
    printf("1\n");
}


void close_file(FILE **addr1,FILE **addr2){
    fclose(*addr1);
    fclose(*addr2);
//  remove("buf.txt");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS"); 
    if (argc!=2){  
        printf("Некорректное число аргументов"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    FILE *addr1, *addr2;
    open_file(argv[1],&addr1,&addr2);
    transform(&addr1,&addr2);
    close_file(&addr1,&addr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Пробовал записывать как и посимвольно, так и по числу - эффект один и тот же. Где я допускаю ошибку?
Пример содержимого файла: `-789 254 355 -98 -48 2`

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как ваши числа расположены в файле.

Comment: @GromovAnton поправил вопрос, добавил пример содержимого. Но я кажется, сам уже понял в чем моя ошибка. Так как я отрицательные числа меняю нулями, то итоговая запись становится короче, и выходит что остаются хвосты от старой записи, так?

Comment: `fputc(x=EOF,*addr2);` Что это? O_o

Comment: @AnT а это я, отчаявшись, пытался как-то впихнуть символ конца файла...